# Cocoa Data Manipulation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoa, listview, persistence

I'd like to know if cocoa has a default way of storing data. If yes what is it? I mean like rails is by default using sqlite...

Also I'm searching for a tutorial on how to use it... Like get data and showing it into a listview, etc...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cocoa has [Core Data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Data) available to manage your applications storage.  [This](http://developer.apple.com/cocoa/coredatatutorial/index.html) is a good place to start learning about Core Data.